# Using variable in sql WHERE clause for Operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not a db admin by any means so if semantics look a bit bizarre, I apologize. 
In SQL Server, is it possible to use a variable for a comparison operator like so?

```
declare @compare = '>';
declare @limit = '5';

select agentId, sessionId, duration
from table_x
where duration @compare @limit
```

I do not want to write a ton of lines depending on what the variable could be, which is why I ask. Not to mention if I throw in another variable, that further makes the amount of lines even larger. Also, I like the fact that it's extensible, so in the event there was an additional operator, it would just process it anyway.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not in a regular query.  You can do this using dynamic SQL.

Comment: You can also do it with 2 variables.. `@UpperLimit` and `@LowerLimit`. (this is assuming you're only looking at > and <). Just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, actually, by invoking different operators via a guard expression:

```
DECLARE @comparison varchar(2) = '>'
DECLARE @limit int 5 = 123

SELECT
    Foo
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    ( @comparson = '>' AND Duration > @limit )
    OR
    ( @comparson = '<' AND Duration < @limit )
    OR
    ( @comparson = '=' AND Duration = @limit )
    OR
    ( @comparson = '<>' AND Duration <> @limit )
```

To generalize this, you can convert this into a UDF and use it in multiple places:

```
CREATE FUNCTION VariableComparison(@comparison AS varchar(2), @value as numeric, @operand as numeric) RETURNS bit AS
BEGIN

    RETURN ( @comparison = '>' AND @value > @operand )
    OR
    ( @comparison = '<' AND @value < @operand )
    OR
    ( @comparison = '=' AND @value = @operand )
    OR
    ( @comparison = '<>' AND @value <> @operand )

END
```

Used like so:

```
SELECT
    ...
WHERE
    dbo.VariableComparison( @comparison, Duration, @limit ) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I thought about doing it this way, but I also have a timeUnit variable (sec, min, hrs) which makes the guard expression pretty long. But it looks like I'll just have to go this route.

Comment: @BobbyT. How are you storing time values? If you're storing data in a normalized (single column) value then you can use fractional/decimal units as operands.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this using dynamic sql, something like

```
declare @compare varchar(2) = '>';
declare @limit int = '5';

declare @dynamicQuery = nvarchar(max) = N'select agentId, sessionId, duration
from table_x
where duration' + @compare + @limit

EXEC(@dynamicQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting varied comparisons for *numbers* is to use `sign()`:

```
where sign(duration - limit) = (case when @compare = '=' then 0
                                     when @compare = '>' then 1
                                     when @compare = '<' then -1
                                end)
```

However, these types of operations in the `WHERE` clause are not recommended because they preclude the use of indexes.  Also, this structure doesn't work for strings or dates, but it does work for numbers.